# Practical uses of downcasting

Tags: oop, downcast

I've finished reading the chapters on polymorphism and inheritance and done all the exercises in my Java books. But I still don't understand why I would need to use downcasting in practice. Could you please give some examples from work or projects where you had to use downcasting?

Comment: Downcasting should be rare in practice.  It is often a sign of a problem with a design.

Answer (score 1):

*Suppose you have a base class, and a class that derives from that base class either directly or indirectly. Then, anytime an object of that base class type is type cast into a derived class type, it is called a Downcast.* You need to downcast to make an instance specific. For example, let `getobject()` be a method which returns an `Object`, since `String` is a subclass of `Object`, this method may return a `String` as well.

**Case (i):**

```
Object o = getObject();
```

Here you have assigned the object returned by the method to an `Object` reference variable. So you can invoke only the methods defined in `Object` class on the instance `o`.

**Case (ii):**

```
Object o = getObject();
if(o instanceof String)
  String s = (String)o;
```

Here, if `getobject()` actually had returned a `String` instance, then you are downcasting it to `String`. The advantage of this is that you can invoke methods defined in `String` on `s` which you couldn't have done in Case(i).